# Spring custom formatter in an external jar

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

In a Spring boot application using Web MVC to develop a REST API. All works fine.

To convert String to ZonedDateTime, I created this annotation :

```
@Target({ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.FIELD, ElementType.PARAMETER, ElementType.ANNOTATION_TYPE})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface DateTimeFormatter {
}
```

Here is the custom formatter :

```
public class ZonedDateTimeFormatter implements Formatter<ZonedDateTime> {

    @Override
    public String print(ZonedDateTime zoneddateTime, Locale locale) {
        return .....
    }

    @Override
    public ZonedDateTime parse(String text, Locale locale) throws ParseException {
        return ......
    }
}
```

And this is how I add the formatter,

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableDiscoveryClient
@EnableHystrix
@Configuration
public class IndexApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    ...

    @Configuration
    public static class ApplicationFormatterRegistrar extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter implements FeignFormatterRegistrar {

        @Override
        public void addFormatters(FormatterRegistry registry) {
            registry.addFormatterForFieldAnnotation(new ZonedDateTimeAnnotationFormatterFactory());
        }

        @Override
        public void registerFormatters(FormatterRegistry registry) {
            registry.addFormatter(new ZonedDateTimeFormatter());
        }
    }
}
```

This is how I test the application (Spring mockmvc) :

```
this.mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(indexResource).build();

......


@Test
    public void should_accept_valid_request() throws Exception {
        when(service.getSomething(id, begin, end)).thenReturn(somevalue);
        mockMvc.perform(
                get("/index/{id}", 1)
                    .param("start", "2011-12-03T10:15:30")
                    .param("end", "2011-12-03T10:15:30")
            ).andExpect(status().isOk());
    }
```

All works fine. The problem is that I would like to put the custom annotation `@DateTimeFormatter` in a common jar for all projects, in this case Spring MVC doesn't register the custom converter ! I don't understand why. 
Your help would be appreciated.

Comment: I Can see the code in github?

Answer (score 2):

I was able to register the custom formatter this way :

```
FormattingConversionService conversionService = new FormattingConversionService();
conversionService.addFormatterForFieldAnnotation(new ZonedDateTimeAnnotationFormatterFactory());
this.mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(indexResource).setConversionService(conversionService).build();
```

I don't know why I should do this for my tests even if the formatter is already registered in the configuration.